# How to pass array of objects to polymer component

Tags: meteor, polymer

I am new to Meteor and experimenting with Meteor + Polymer and have one question. It looks simple but it doesn't work:-(

I want to pass array of objects to created  polymer component (see below)

In Meteor template "**userShowDashboard**":

This component works

```
<belo-test 
    items='[{"title": "Title 1"}, {"title": "Title 2"}]'
    header='Test HEADER'>
</belo-test>
```

but, this one NOT (no items are shown)

```
<belo-test 
    items={{getItems}}
    header='Test HEADER'>
</belo-test>
```

This is meteor helper function

```
Template.userShowDashboard.helpers
  getItems: ->
    [{"title": "Title 1"}, {"title": "Title 2"}]
```

polymer component

```
<polymer-element name="belo-test" attributes="items header">
  <template>
          <core-submenu label="{{header}}" icon="apps" active>
            <template repeat="{{item in items}}">  
                <a href="#">
                  <paper-item data-action="switch-project">
                    <core-icon icon="chevron-right"></core-icon>
                      {{item.title}}
                  </paper-item>
                </a>                
              </template>  
          </core-submenu> 
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('belo-test',{
    items: []
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this and let me know:

```js
Template.userShowDashboard.helpers
  items: ->
    JSON.stringify([{"title": "Title 1"}, {"title": "Title 2"}])
  header: ->
    "This is the Header"
```

...with this template code:

```html
<belo-test 
    items="{{items}}"
    header="{{header}}">
</belo-test>
```